Auth Setup for NextJS frontend and ExpressJS backend with MongoDB
I am building a full stack app with Next JS frontend and Express JS backend with MongoDB as the database. I want to implement authentication using email and password, as well as with Google Provider. I also want to verify the email if the user signs in using email and password. I do have a custom signup and login page. What is the best way to implement auth for this setup, considering the app will have mostly free users?
I have looked up several options but couldn't find any documentation or guide that suits this use case. NextAuth documentation seems to be hard while Clerk is expensive.

By verify token or OTP token do you mean like a 2-factor auth after a user logs in with email + password or social auth as the primary factor?

I meant to simply verify the email. If a user signs in using email and password, I need to verify the email. The verification can be by any means, not necessarily 2 factor authentication, like a simple verification token or OTP.

Disclaimer - I work for Pangea now :)
Yeah NextAuth can get kind of tedious with respect to configuring SMTP servers, etc.
Pangea AuthN is pretty easy to configure with React / Next frontends since it has a hosted login provider where you can configure all the login flows (Email, SMS, or TOTP) directly on the Pangea platform without having to configure any of the auth logic in your code and it provides 5000 MAUs free + $0.05 / MAU after
If you're interested try it out and let me know your thoughts :)
https://pangea.cloud/services/authn/

i am provide you code for controller
// controllers/userController.js
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const otpGenerator = require('otp-generator');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Create user in the database
    const request = req.body; // No need to use await here
    const UserCount = await User.countDocuments();
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: request.email });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        UserCount,
        success: false,
        message: 'User With This Email Already Exists',
      });
    }

    const otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, {
      upperCaseAlphabets: false,
      specialChars: false,
      lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
      digits: true,
    });
    // Create user with the generated OTP
    const user = await User.create({
      ...request,
      otp,
      role: Boolean(UserCount) ? request.role || 'user' : 'super admin',
    });

    // Generate JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: user._id,
        // email: user.email,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: '7d',
      }
    );
    // Path to the HTML file
    const htmlFilePath = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      'src/email-templates',
      'otp.html'
    );

    // Read HTML file content
    let htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(htmlFilePath, 'utf8');

    // Replace the placeholder with the OTP and user email
    htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<h1>[\s\d]*<\/h1>/g, `<h1>${otp}</h1>`);
    htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/usingyourmail@gmail\.com/g, user.email);

    // Create nodemailer transporter
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // Your Gmail password
      },
    });

    // Email options
    let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
      to: user.email, // User's email
      subject: 'Verify your email',
      html: htmlContent, // HTML content with OTP and user email
    };

    // Send email
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Created User Successfully',
      otp,
      token,
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message,
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};
const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = await req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'User Not Found' });
    }

    if (!user.password) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'User Password Not Found' });
    }

    const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'Incorrect Password' });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: '7d',
      }
    );

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Login Successfully',
      token,
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        email: user.email,
        cover: user.cover,
        gender: user.gender,
        phone: user.phone,
        address: user.address,
        city: user.city,
        country: user.country,
        zip: user.zip,
        state: user.state,
        about: user.about,
        role: user.role,
        wishlist: products,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error.message });
  }
};

const forgetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const request = await req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: request.email });

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'User Not Found ' });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '7d',
    });
    // Constructing the link with the token
    const resetPasswordLink = `${request.origin}/auth/reset-password/${token}`;

    // Path to the HTML file
    const htmlFilePath = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      'src/email-templates',
      'forget.html'
    );

    // Read HTML file content
    let htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(htmlFilePath, 'utf8');

    // Replace the href attribute of the <a> tag with the reset password link
    // htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
    //   /href="javascript:void\(0\);"/g,
    //   `href="${resetPasswordLink}"`
    // )
    htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
      /href="javascript:void\(0\);"/g,
      `href="${resetPasswordLink}"`
    );
    // Create nodemailer transporter
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // Your Gmail password
      },
    });

    // Email options
    let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
      to: user.email, // User's email
      subject: 'Verify your email',
      html: htmlContent, // HTML content with OTP and user email
    };

    // Send email synchronously
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Forgot Password Email Sent Successfully.',
      token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};

const resetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token, newPassword } = await req.body;

    // Verify the token
    let decoded;
    try {
      decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Invalid Or Expired Token. Please Request A New One.',
      });
    }

    // Find the user by ID from the token
    const user = await User.findById(decoded._id).select('password');

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'User Not Found ',
      });
    }
    if (!newPassword || !user.password) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message:
          'Invalid Data. Both NewPassword And User Password Are Required.',
      });
    }

    // Check if the new password is the same as the old password
    const isSamePassword = await bcrypt.compare(newPassword, user.password);
    if (isSamePassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'New Password Must Be Different From The Old Password.',
      });
    }
    // Update the user's password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Password Updated Successfully.',
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};

const verifyOtp = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, otp } = await req.body;

    // Find the user with the provided email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).maxTimeMS(30000).exec();

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'User Not Found' });
    }

    // Check if the OTP is already verified
    if (user.isVerified) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'OTP Has Already Been Verified',
      });
    }

    // Verify the OTP using an if-else statement
    let message = '';
    if (otp === user.otp) {
      // Update the user's status to verified
      user.isVerified = true;
      await user.save();
      message = 'OTP Verified Successfully';
      return res.status(201).json({ success: true, message });
    } else {
      message = 'Invalid OTP';
      return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};

const resendOtp = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = await req.body;

    // Find the user with the provided email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).maxTimeMS(30000).exec();

    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ success: false, message: 'User Not Found' });
    }

    if (user.isVerified) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'OTP Has Already Been Verified',
      });
    }
    // Generate new OTP
    const otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, {
      upperCaseAlphabets: false,
      specialChars: false,
      lowerCaseAlphabets: false,
      digits: true,
    });
    // Update the user's OTP
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {
      otp: otp.toString(),
    });

    // Path to the HTML file
    const htmlFilePath = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      'src/email-templates',
      'otp.html'
    );

    // Read HTML file content
    let htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(htmlFilePath, 'utf8');

    // Replace the placeholder with the OTP and user email
    htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<h1>[\s\d]*<\/h1>/g, `<h1>${otp}</h1>`);
    htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/usingyourmail@gmail\.com/g, user.email);

    // Create nodemailer transporter
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // Your Gmail password
      },
    });

    // Email options
    let mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL, // Your Gmail email
      to: user.email, // User's email
      subject: 'Verify your email',
      html: htmlContent, // HTML content with OTP and user email
    };

    // Send email
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    // Return the response
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'OTP Resent Successfully',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};
module.exports = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
  forgetPassword,
  resetPassword,
  verifyOtp,
  resendOtp,
};


Create a .env file in the root of your backend directory and add EMAIL= EMAIL_PASSWORD= this two field
